# SQL inner join performance advice

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I need performance advice about this sql statement. I have two tables "cross" (about 16 000 rows) and "data" (about 100 000 rows). Problem is slow performance. I need get "title" column from "data", where data.partnum = cross.sku. Problem is, that I have multiple same values "data.partnum", so what I need is limiting result to only first row from inner join. Im tried with subquery in select statement, but it was slow. Can you help me? Im amateur about databases - so I dont have any primary key or index key. Thanks

```
SELECT '[cross]'
    , IFNULL(d2.title, "") as title
    , c2.maker
    , c2.partnum
    , c2.price
    , c2.sku
FROM `cross` c2
LEFT JOIN data d2 ON d2.partnum = c2.sku
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY c2.partnum
```

Comment: Did you create the index for `sku` and `partnum`? Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: eh ! nice, it works much better, i created index for sku and partnum, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT '[cross]', COALESCE(d2.title, '') as title,
      c2.maker, c2.partnum, c2.price, c2.sku
FROM `cross` c2 LEFT JOIN
     data d2
     ON d2.partnum = c2.sku
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY c2.partnum;
```

This obviously suggests an index on `data(partnum, title)`.  But, there are several big issues with the query:

- What is `cross.sku` and `cross.partnum`?  It is really strange that the `join` condition is not on `partnum` in both tables (or on `sku` in both tables).
- What is the purpose of the aggregation?  You have no aggregation functions.
- I have a preference for `COALESCE()` because it is ANSI standard.

If you want an arbitrary matching `title`, then I would recommend a correlated subquery if `cross.partnum` is unique:

```
SELECT '[cross]',
       coalesce((select d2.title
                 from data d2
                 where d2.partnum = c2.sku
                 limit 1
                ), '') as title,
      c2.maker, c2.partnum, c2.price, c2.sku
FROM `cross` c2 
WHERE 1=1;
```

Assuming that `cross.partnum` is unique (as suggested by the lack of aggregation functions in the original query), then this should be much faster, with an index on `data(partnum, title)`.

Comment: I vote for the second query, not the first, as being the 'best'.